# In Linux, how do I compile and install code for different versions of Python?

Tags: python, linux, installation, pygtk, compilation

See the title for the question. In particular, in Linux, how do I compile and install PyGTK 2.24 for different versions of Python?

Do I have to specify options and paths while using "configure, make, make install" or "setup.py?"

Comment: does pygtk work for your version of python?

Comment: The README says "Python 2.3.5 or higher", and my versions are higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#python2.6 setup.py
```

or

```
#python2.5 setup.py
```

will make the difference

Edit: for PyGTK please [refer to this FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=all#1.10)

Comment: Using setup.py, I got the following message: Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file. I may have compiled from source most of my Python versions.

Comment: Did you read the `INSTALL` file? Usually they have some nice info (seriously).

Comment: @Winston: Added info related to PyGTK in my answer, I hope it can help.